# Sping RestController not responding to request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

I am just trying to implement a sample rest controller on spring boot for learning. When i am sending the request through web browser i am getting a white label error.

[image]

My applications context path is set to `/learn`. Below are my source files, project structure and pom.xml.

[image]

**TestController.java**

```
package com.practice.learn.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/learn")
public class TestController {

    TestController(){
        System.out.println("TestController initialized");
    }
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String testMethod() {
        System.out.println("Inside test method");
        return "This is sample text";
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.8</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.practice</groupId>
    <artifactId>learn</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>learn</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**LearnApplication.java**

```
package com.practice.learn;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class LearnApplication {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LearnApplication.class, args);
    }
    

}
```

**application.properties**

```
server.port=8081
server.servlet.context-path=/learn
```

Comment: i am using server.port = 8081 in application.properties

Comment: Can you post your properties file and other configuration for better understanding ?

Comment: Added. There aren't any configurations i have done...just set the port and context path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you already set the servlet context path as '/learn' in your configuration file, you do not need to add '/learn' again in the RequestMapping in your controller. just remove it and let us know.

Comment: I already tried it by removing it on my class it didn't work..but now after reading your answer i tried again and it worked, dont know why but thanks.

Comment: I would say the opposite. In Spring Boot application you generally don't need context path. Unless you have some specific requirements, remove context path and set controller requestmapping path as needed.
Your application occupies port 8081. You won't be able to run some another application on this port, so you don't need to further distinguish you app with context path. It will be alone on specified port.